# adminjs, update mongoDB with custom component in list

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, adminjs

Could not understand what is wrong while trying to update a param of an object in DB through custom component in adminjs. Receiving

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Probably need something additional with data manipulation on mongoDB. Can't understand what exactly with this custom actions. Maybe someone can help with this

`index.js`

```
import AdminJS from "adminjs"
import { buildRouter as AdminJSExpress } from "@adminjs/express"
import express from "express"
import mongoose from "mongoose"
import * as AdminJSMongoose from "@adminjs/mongoose"

import { componentLoader } from "./componentLoader.js"
import { OfferStatus } from "./offerStatus.js"

const PORT = 3000
const DB = "..."

AdminJS.registerAdapter({
  Resource: AdminJSMongoose.Resource,
  Database: AdminJSMongoose.Database,
})

const startAdminJS = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(DB, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB")

    const app = express()

    const admin = new AdminJS({
      resources: [OfferStatus],
      componentLoader: componentLoader,
    })

    const adminRouter = AdminJSExpress(admin)

    app.use(admin.options.rootPath, adminRouter)
    admin.watch()

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(
        `Listening on port ${PORT}, AdminJS server started on URL: http://localhost:${PORT}${admin.options.rootPath}`
      )
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error starting AdminJS", error)
  }
}

startAdminJS()
```

`entity`

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  network_id: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  offer_status: { type: Boolean, required: true },
})

export const Order = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema)
```

`resource options`

```
import { Order } from "./order.entity.js"
import { Components } from "./componentLoader.js"

const toggleStatusAction = {
  name: "toggleStatus",
  actionType: "record",
  isVisible: true,
  handler: async (request, context) => {
    const { record, resource } = context
    if (record.isValid() && record.param("offer_status") !== undefined) {
      await resource.update(request.params.recordId, {
        offer_status: !record.param("offer_status"),
      })
      return {
        record: record.toJSON(),
        notice: {
          message: "Status successfully toggled",
          type: "success",
        },
      }
    } else {
      throw new AdminJS.ValidationError(
        {
          offer_status: {
            message: "Status could not be toggled",
          },
        },
        {
          message: "An error occurred during status toggle",
        }
      )
    }
  },
  components: {
    list: Components.CustomCheckbox,
  },
}

export const OfferStatus = {
  resource: Order,
  options: {
    properties: {
      _id: {
        type: "string",
        isVisible: {
          edit: false,
          show: false,
          list: false,
          filter: false,
        },
      },
      offer_status: {
        type: "boolean",
        components: {
          list: Components.CustomCheckbox,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  actions: {
    toggleStatus: toggleStatusAction,
  },
}
```

`custom component`

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { CheckBox } from "@adminjs/design-system"

const CustomCheckbox = ({ record, property }) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(record.params[property.name])

  const handleChange = async () => {
    const newValue = !checked
    setChecked(newValue)

    try {
      await fetch(
        `/admin/api/resources/Order/records/${record.id}/toggleStatus`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            recordId: record.id,
          }),
        }
      )
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error to change status", error)
      setChecked(!newValue)
    }
  }

  return <CheckBox checked={checked} onChange={handleChange} />
}

export default CustomCheckbox
```